# Where has the Gmail Compose/Reply window pop-out command gone?

Tags: gmail

Until today, on latest Chrome browser, Gmail Compose/Reply window offered a button at top right to pop-out to a separate tab.

Now, it is not there.

Where is it now? If anywhere....

Comment: Hold `SHIFT` when clicking on the **Exit full screen** icon [e.g. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoQUs.png) in the top right corner of the partially popped out window.

Comment: Thanks. That led me to the more direct answer - posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHIFT-click the Compose/Reply window's (mis-named) Full Screen button:

[image]

Note: SHIFT hover changes the button to a tooltip-less single arrow:

[image]